# Refreshing div with jquery not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using the jquery news ticker from (http://jquerynewsticker.com/) as my footer. The footer is only loaded once, hence if I get new data to my DB, the new data won't show.

I want that the news ticker div is refreshed by itself every x seconds, so if there is new data in my DB, that it will be shown.

the news ticker is currently:

```
<div class="footer" id="footerticker">
    <ul id="js-news" class="js-hidden">
    <c:forEach items="${handcarryTicker}" var="handcarry2">
        <li class="news-item">
            <td>LGP: ${handcarry2.item1}</td>
            <td>${handcarry2.item2}</td>
        </li>
    </c:forEach>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I found several solutions for refreshing a div, but unfortunately, they did not work for me.
The footer is loaded and shown 5 seconds and then it disappears.
How can I make it that the footer does not disappear after 5 seconds and just refreshes?

My current script is:

```
<script>
    function refresh() {
        setInterval(() => {
            $('#footerticker').load(window.location.href +  ' #footerticker')
        }, 5000);
    }
$(document).ready(refresh);
</script>
```

Comment: Nothing matches `$('#block')` in your HTML markup

Comment: That was a typo, edited it now. Problem is still the same

Comment: What's the response of `window.location.href +  ' #footerticker'` (in your network tab) ?

Comment: @JeremyThille Can you please tell me how to check that on firefox?

Comment: Why, in your dev tools, of course. Next to the console tab, there's a network tab where you can see all HTTP requests, with the payload, the response from the server, etc.